# Making two elements stay next to each other when one has a width of 100%

Tags: css

I am trying to make a `text` field expand to it's full width whilst still allowing room for the submit button next to it, however it doesn't seem like I can get it to work.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNdvWY

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="foo" class="tb">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</div>

<div class="wrapper small">
  <input type="text" name="foo" class="tb">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 510px;
}

.wrapper.small {
  width: 255px;
}

input.tb {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 456px;
}
```

You will see how the first one works because of the `max-width` set, but the smaller one drops the button to the next line.

I have tried this with `floats` with the same results. Is the only way to do this with `tables`?

Additionally, `white-space: nowrap;` doesn't work as it overflows the parent; which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to the container of your elements

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJrWBX)**

Or a better way if you don't want the button outside the parent width would be wrapping the `text input`into a span with this properties:

```
span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and make your button float to the right (and change html order)

Like in this **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wazJPY)**

(You may add `padding-right` to the span to make space between both elements)

Third possible option may be floating both elements to the left (no html change order) and if the buttom width is known and fixed You can set the width of your input as:

```
width:calc (100% - XXpx);
```

as in this **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVRprr)** (I have added `box-sizing: border-box;`so paddings and margins won't mess up the `calc`property)

Comment: This does not really solve the issue since the input will still take 100% of the parent container's width, and the button will just overflow the parent.

Comment: Also, changing the html order is not a good way usability-wise, since users might be using the keyboard and tabbing throught the fields. It's bad if the button comes before the input tab-wise then. Actually, this turns out to be surprisingly difficult to solve adequately.

Comment: Well, that's why you have the `html` `tab-index` atrribute: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVRpvo

Comment: Personally I like the first option best as I don't like having the html order back to front. :)

Comment: But yes, I just tested in my own code and it does overflow the parent as stated. :(

Comment: Well, that's all the options I know in this particular example (without using javascript). There may be more ways to achieve it but it doesn't mean this answer is not valid and could be the right solution for other people with the same problem. However, good luck with your project.

Comment: Btw, IF your buttoms will have a fixed width, another option you may look for would to float both elements left and give your input `width:calc(100% - XXpx);`

Comment: Actually my submit button does have a fixed width, so that is one thing. I can give that a try - thank you!

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez That worked a treat. Feel free to add it as an option in your answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to wrap your elements inside a `div` and set `disaply: table` like:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 510px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: teal;
  display: table-cell;
}
.wrapper.small {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 255px;
}
input.tb {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 456px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="foo" class="tb">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper small">
    <input type="text" name="foo" class="tb">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
  </div>
</div>
```